# How to redirect user to desired store?

Tags: multistore

I'm running Magento Enterprise edition with 3 stores on single domain, I would like to have an option to the user to select his desired store. i.e I'm having 3 stores based on location, i would like to ask the user to select his desired location, because my products vary from location to location. Any solution pls!!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you much code but the idea is as follows.
Create a new customer attribute, dropdown with a custom source model. [Here is one example](http://magentotutorial.org/how-to-add-new-customer-attributes-in-magento/) but you will find many.  And here is an example on how to create an [attribute with a custom source](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html). It's for products but it works the same for customers
Your custom source should contain all your websites or store views.
Now the customer will be able to chose his preferred store.

Now all you need is that when the customer logs in to be redirected to the preferred store.

For that create an observer on the event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost` that checks the customer's preferred website or store view and redirects to it.
Something like this (untested code):

```
public function redirectToPreferredStore() {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if (!$customer->getId()){
        return $this;
    }
    $preferredStore = $customer->getPreferredStore(); //use the code of the attribute you just added
    //if no preferred store or preferred store is the current one, do nothing
    if (!$preferredStore || $preferredStore == Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()){
        return $this;
    }
    //if not on preferred store redirect to the desired one
    $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array('_store'=>$preferredStore));
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
}
```

The code above is based on a customer selecting store views. If you want him to select websites you may need to change it a little, before redirecting you have to load the website object and get the default store id of that website.

Answer (score 0):

By default pretty much all skins (except perhaps some custom made ones) have this functionality built in. See `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/stores.phtml` for more information.